# Выдает ошибку Cannot find reference

Tags: python, python-3.x

Только начинаю изучать Python и решил написать игру. Выдает ошибку, что

```
   #Cannot find reference 'init' in '__ init__.py'
    pygame.init()
```

И тоже самое с

```
 pygame.quit()
```

C чем может быть связана данная проблема и как её решить?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode ((800,800))
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

crashed = False

while not crashed:

    for even in pygame.event.get():
        if even.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        print(even)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Вот полное описание ошибки

```
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: No module named 'pygame.base'
>>> pygame.init()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    pygame.init()
NameError: name 'pygame' is not defined
```

Comment: А вы случаем ваш файл не назвали `pygame.py`? Выполните первые две строчки в интерактивном режиме интерпретатора, и посмотрите будет ли там работать? Приведите полный стэк ошибки.

Comment: @Avernial - Нет, файл назван по другому. Я прикрепил к посту полное описание ошибки. Как мне кажется скорее всего у меня проблема с тем, что я как-то не так установил модуль pygame.

Comment: А как вы устанавливали?

Comment: @Avernial -  С данного сайта - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame скачал pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl. Далее распаковал его, как .zip и скинул в папку Python34 файлы, что куда кидал если честно не помню, делал по какому-то видео. Если не сложно не могли бы вы скинуть ссылку на ресурсы или рассказать, как это делать правильно ?

Comment: У вас установлен python версии 3.4, а библиотеку вы скачали для версии 3.6 поэтому и не работает. Самый простой способ устанавливать библиотеки это воспользоваться python package index, т.е. набрать в командной строке `pip install pygame`

Comment: Также можно скачать файл с сайта http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame, а потом его установить. Например для python3.4 64-bit, надо скачать файл pygame‑1.9.3‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl, а потом его установить, набрав в командной строке: `pin install pygame‑1.9.3‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl`

Comment: @Avernial - Огромное спасибо, что помог разобраться в этом всем)